# How to get value first item my custom listview without setOnItemClickListener Android?

Tags: android

How to get value first item  my custom listview without setOnItemClickListener Android ?

this my code

```
// list is my listview adapter

            list.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {

            public void onRefresh() {

                View view = (View) list.getItemAtPosition(0);
                    String Title= ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Title))
                            .getText().toString();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this, 
                            judul, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

                String url = "http://blablabla.com/android/inbox.json/index.php?act=new_update&id_title="+Title;
                 grabURL(url); 

            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work if I understood your question correctly, `String fistItem = list.get(0).toString();`